# Partitions uses in default Mac OS installation?

Tags: partition, recovery

I plan to install Linux on my Macbook Pro and before removing an important partition, I'd like to know what I need to keep in order to be able to do a recovery to MacOS in case I need to.

For information, here's what I currently have on my macbook :

- EFI : 200Mo
- Apple Core storage : 465.1Go
- Apple Recovery : 619.9Mo

Here's the fdisk output : (sorry, in French)

[image]

I believe I can remove the "Apple Core Storage", but can I also remove the EFI or no?

The idea is to be able to launch a Apple Recovery in case I need it and get back my computer like it was when I bought it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please included the output of whatever tool you used to list the partitions (screenshot or copy/paste from Terminal)?

Comment: I've added it (Sorry it's in french)

Comment: Hint: You can also use my tool "iBored", which has a GUI. It may make it easier to look at the partitions, copy blocks, etc. See apps.tempel.org. Also, instead of "fdisk", you should use "diskutil" on OSX. It's more suitable to look at and modify OSX partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep the EFI partition in order to be able to boot OSX. You could, however, install an alternative boot loader, such as "rEFInd".

You do not need to keep the "Apple Recovery" partition, but you should, because if you mess up the normal Mac partition so that you cannot boot from it any more, you might still be able to boot into the Recovery partition and fix the OSX system from it.

You could also copy both the EFI and Recovery partitions to a new disk, e.g. to an external disk, and then boot from it. If that works, then you'd be safer playing with the partitions on your main drive, seeing what works, and still be able to boot from the external disk, because the Mac's boot ROM will search every connected internal and external disk for an EFI partition in order to see if it can boot from it.

To test this, hold down the Option (alt) key when the Mac starts up - then you will get a list of bootable partitions.

For installing Linux, I suggest you do these steps:

1. Get a large enough external disk and make a backup of each of your partitions, using a block copy method, or by using OS X's Disk Utility, with the "New disk image from ..." command from the File menu. You could also try my tool "iBored" for this.
2. Boot OSX and open Disk Utility. Select the disk, then "Partitions". Select the large OSX partition and click the [+] button to add a new partition. Make it large enough for your Linux system. This will then make the OSX partition smaller if there's enough free space on it. Now you have a new free partition to install Linux on.
3. See if you can install rEFInd and see if that supports booting into Linux (it should, but I have not tried it myself).
4. If something goes wrong, you can always restore from your external backup.

Comment: Awesome thank you. So once I've backup the EFI + Recovery on an other disk, I can wipe the SSD and play with a 100% full Linux installation. Whenever I need to revert to MacOs, I just have to plug the backup, restart and it will work, right? (just to be sure)

Comment: In fact you need none of the partitions! The EFI partition is **not** needed to boot to OS X Internet Recovery Mode, if you Mac allows this (newer than 2010/2011)!

Comment: Yes, you can copy your entire OSX system partition to an external disk. But first, format the disk in GUID partition mode, using OSX's Disk Utility. That'll create the correct EFI parameters on it, in case it matters (not 100% sure). Then use Disk Utility's "Restore" tab to copy the OSX partition from your Mac to your external disk. Then see if you can boot from the external disk when you hold down the alt key at startup. If that works, feel free to wipe your SSD. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you :) I was wondering, if, in any case, I loose my USB Key with the restore system on it. Is there a way to get it online legally?